# using brew install that compile the project locally

Tags: compilation, homebrew

I'm working on migrating my project to the new Apple Silicon architecture (arm64).

One of my 3rd party libraries still doesn't have arm64 version on supplier website but luckily it's an open source project so I wanted to compile it myself locally.

Unfortunately, the project docs have missing prerequisites regarding how to compile, but apparently home-brew already provides this lib built under arm64 and can be deployed using `brew install`.

For security reasons I wish to compile it locally, So I'd like to see how brew compile it.

I was wondering if there's any way to use `brew install` so that it also compile the project locally and not just copy its pre-made targets to my machine.

Thanks !